# Keyboard shortcuts for evince annotation?

Tags: shortcut-keys, evince, annotation

I would like to make <kbd>c</kbd> a shortcut for inserting a comment and <kbd>h</kbd> a shortcut for highlighting. Other keyboard shortcuts could do, e.g., if modifier keys are required. Pressing one of these keys would be equivalent to pressing the annotation icons in the toolbar:

[image]

... so that clicking/selecting using the mouse afterward would perform the desired action. This would immensely improve my reading flow! Is there a way to do this?

An added bonus would be a way to map <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to deleting the last annotation.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I ended up using Master PDF Editor which does all of this, includes OCR, etc.

Comment: But that's not free, right?

Comment: Actually it has a good free version! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

The feature [was added just one month ago (Aug 10, 2018) to evince](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/merge_requests/54).

I guess it will be available in the next evince version 3.31. The shortcuts in the addition are "S" to add text annotation and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to add highlight annotations.

Comment: Sorry, I have Evince version 3.28.4 and the Keyboard shortcuts doesn't work for me

Comment: @AviMehenwal, did you read the answer? It's only available from 3.31